# Run vba script once .xlsx file was opened

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA and I would like to run following code everytime i open the file. (which is update formula) I do not want to `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + F9` manually.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
End Sub
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: use the `Workbook_Open()` sub/event in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

Comment: hi @mehow, i tried to save the xlsx file once i put "Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
End Sub" to ThisWorkbook. But it do not allow me to save the file.

Comment: @user: You need to save as an XLSM file (or an XLSB) as XLSX files strip out all macro (ie VBA) code.

Comment: how about just xls? thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this macro to the open event of your workbook.

for more info have look at [this](http://visualbasic.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/vb-vba-l/how-to-launch-an-excel-2010-vba-macro-automatically-5111220)